# RealityKit vs SceneKit vs Metal – High-Quality Rendering

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, metal, realitykit

I'm creating an iOS app that I intend to display realistic/high-quality renders within AR. Whilst experimenting with these 3 options, I'm still unsure which of them I should go forward with developing my app's framework around: ***SceneKit***, ***RealityKit*** and ***Metal***.

I've read that SceneKit is built on top of Metal, but I'm not sure whether its worth the time/effort programming any custom shaders as opposed to using what SceneKit can offer by default. Regarding RealityKit, I don't need any of the animations or special effects that it offers, just the photorealistic rendering side.

***Which of the three is the best to develop for AR and High-Quality Model Rendering***?

Answer (score 282):

**Updated**: March 07, 2024.

#### TL;DR

---

This post is not only about RealityKit, SceneKit & Metal, but also about related frameworks.

---

## RealityKit

[image]

RealityKit is the youngest SDK in Apple family of rendering technologies. This high-level framework was released in 2019. It's made for AR / VR projects, has simplified settings for [multi-user experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007941/realitykit-entity-synchronization-is-always-nil/60494389#60494389) and can be used on iOS, visionOS, macOS and tvOS. RealityKit performs [multi-threaded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/improving_the_performance_of_a_realitykit_app/reducing_cpu_utilization_in_your_realitykit_app) rendering, async loading and provides a networking layer to implement state synchronization. Vision Pro headset supports [foveated rendering](https://www.tobii.com/blog/what-is-foveated-rendering#) based on RealityKit engine.

There's no Objective-C legacy, RealityKit supports Swift and Metal Shading Language, and rather declarative syntax, like the one in SwiftUI. The main feature of RealityKit is its ability to customize Reality Composer Pro and Reality Composer scenes, and of course, this framework can be a powerful addition to ARKit. In iOS RealityKit, content contains the following **entities**: *ModelEntity*, *AnchorEntity*, *TriggerVolume*, [BodyTrackedEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299960/how-to-get-human-body-height-from-arbodyanchor/71308235#71308235), *PointLight*, *SpotLight*, *[DirectionalLight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314225/realitykit-wont-show-more-than-one-directionallight/72314614#72314614)* and *PerspectiveCamera* that have **components** and can be created from **resources** like ModelEntity. In visionOS, there are significantly more [components](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/component) than in iOS/macOS.

The framework runs the [Entity Component System](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-entity-component-system-ecs-bfe0520e0e8e) (ECS) architectural pattern on the CPU to manage tasks like physics, animations, audio processing, and network synchronization. But RK is also heavily relies on GPU hardware to perform multithreaded rendering. RealityKit has eight [materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828648/how-to-add-material-to-modelentity-programatically-in-realitykit/56849454#56849454): `MaterialX` (open standard launched by ILM) for visionOS, `UnlitMaterial`, `SimpleMaterial`, `PortalMaterial` for visionOS, `PhysicallyBasedMaterial` (with 18 AOVs for controlling surface look), `OcclusionMaterial`, `VideoMaterial` and, of course, [CustomMaterial](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-custom-material-with-metal-shaders-e7e1f7077e69) for iOS.

[image]

Pay particular attention to shadows on iOS – devices with A9...A11 chipsets produce projective (a.k.a. depth map) shadows, but on devices with A12+ and M1+ chipsets we can render raytraced shadows. Maybe your choice could be [fake shadows](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-fake-shadows-for-stationary-models-78387aabf42c). Many contemporary render features in iOS RealityKit are `On` by default: camera's depth of field, face/person occlusion, grounding shadows, motion blur, camera grain, etc. Note that keeping the main CPU thread below 16 ms timeframe does not guarantee 60 fps performance on iPhone, and keeping the main CPU thread below 12 ms timeframe doesn't guarantee 90 fps performance on Vision Pro.

[image]

iOS RealityKit reads in `.usdz`, `.rcproject` and `.reality` file formats. Supports [transform and asset animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335075/how-to-animate-a-models-rotation-in-realitykit/59336962#59336962), rigid body dynamics, [mesh descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71544920/how-to-render-a-canonical-face-mesh-with-realitykit/74913360#74913360), HDR Image Based Lighting, [particle system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474607/particle-system-in-realitykit/76474627#76474627) (at the moment particles work in visionOS and tvOS only), playback [animation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513552/slow-down-the-arsession-without-slowing-down-the-camera-feed/72514547#72514547), PBR materials, [raycasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466773/what-is-the-real-benefit-of-using-raycast-in-arkit-and-realitykit/56467767#56467767) and [spatial audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75034703/can-i-use-playaudio-to-resume-playback-after-stopping/75037831?noredirect=1#comment132420792_75037831). All scene models must be tethered with [anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502) (however, in visionOS anchors are optional). Framework automatically generates and uses [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), which are a series of progressively low-rez variants of objects' textures that improve render times when applied to distant objects. RealityKit works with a dynamically changing polygonal mesh generated with the help of [Scene Reconstruction](https://medium.com/@arkit/arkit-911-scene-reconstruction-with-a-lidar-scanner-57ff0a8b247e) feature. I wanna add a few words about `AR Quick Look` - it's a zero-configuration framework that's built on the RealityKit engine and conceived as a tool for fast AR visualization.

visionOS app's sample code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1))
            model.position.z = -1.0
           
            let anchor = AnchorEntity(.head)
            anchor.anchoring.trackingMode = .continuous
            anchor.addChild(model)
            
            content.add(anchor)
        }
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**: RealityKit gives you a high-quality render technology and up-to-date AR capabilities out-of-the-box. Supports LiDAR Scanner. On macOS 12+ and iOS 17+, it supports [Photogrammetry](https://medium.com/geekculture/realitykit-911-photogrammetry-77659381af50) tools. Plays Reality Composer's behaviors through its [Notification API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115018/receiving-xcode-notification-on-reality-composer-animation-end/71118245#71118245). RealityKit can be used as standalone framework, or as a partner of ARKit and MetalKit. iOS version has an access to `fragment/pixel shaders` and `geometry modifiers` via Metal scripting and CustomMaterials. Reality family software has CLI and GUI tools for fast and easy [USDZ-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018). Now RealityKit's apps work in Xcode's visionOS simulator. On visionOS, RealityKit runs in an async context.

RealityKit works with UIKit storyboards and with SwiftUI interfaces. It has a minimum of a boilerplate code. For example, RealityKit has a very simple setup for [models' collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191009/reality-composer-custom-collision-between-entities-of-different-scenes) and gestures (pan, rotate, pinch), including alternative [2D gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528947/how-can-i-move-a-modelentity-along-the-y-axis-using-gesture/71531053#71531053). Supports tracked raycasting in iOS. And there's a composition over inheritance, so it's rather a Protocol Oriented Programming framework – `tight coupling` in most cases is no longer a problem in your code. RealityKit fits perfectly with the `Combine` reactive paradigm, which helps handling publishers, subscribers and asynchronous events. A prime example of it, is the [subscribe(to:on:_:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577468/how-to-implement-a-billboard-effect-lookat-camera-in-realitykit/72261373#72261373) generic instance method that returns an object representing the subscription to an event stream, like `SceneEvents.Update.self` which triggered once per frame interval (60 fps and 90 fps, respectively).

RealityKit's visionOS views are [RealityView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76747287/what-is-the-difference-between-model3d-and-realityview-in-visionos/76747520#76747520) and Model3D.

```swift
@available(visionOS 1.0, *)
@available(iOS, unavailable)
public struct RealityView<Content> : View where Content : View
```

---

```swift
@available(xrOS 1.0, *)
@available(iOS, unavailable)
public struct Model3D<Content> : View where Content : View
```

RealityKit's iOS/macOS view is ARView.

```swift
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, *)
@objc open class ARView : ARViewBase
```

---

```
typealias ARViewBase = NSView            // AppKit view
typealias ARViewBase = UIView            // UIKit view
```

## SceneKit

[image]

SceneKit is a high-level framework as well. The oldest one in Apple family of rendering technologies. It was released in 2012. SceneKit was conceived for VR and can be run on iOS, macOS, tvOS and watchOS. For AR projects you can use it only in conjunction with ARKit. SceneKit supports both [Objective-C](https://medium.com/@arkit/scenekit-911-is-swift-app-faster-than-objective-c-app-a6fbfde98214) and Swift. In SceneKit the main unit is a **node** (*SCNNode class*) that has its own hierarchy and can store a **light** (SCNLight), or a **camera** (SCNCamera), or a **geometry** (SCNGeometry), or a [particle system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836318/wheres-the-particle-system-file-in-scenekit-in-xcode-11-3-1/60902081#60902081) (SCNParticleSystem), or **audio players** (SCNAudioPlayer). The main advantage of SceneKit – it's highly customizable, it can change geometry and materials at runtime, it has [morphers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmorpher), skinners and [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnconstraint), it renders a scene up to 120 fps. There are `Blinn`, `Constant`, `Lambert`, `Phong`, `ShadowOnly` and `PBR` shaders.

[Occlusion shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772265/occlusion-material-or-hold-out-shader-in-arkit-and-scenekit/50784115#50784115) is also available for us in SceneKit but in a custom form (there's no out-of-the-box occlusion material here like we can find in RealityKit). In case you need a video material in SCNScene you should assign an `AVPlayer` object to SceneKit's `diffuse.contents` or use SpriteKit's scene with `SKVideoNode`.

[image]

SceneKit allows you perform custom rendering using [SCNProgram](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnprogram?language=objc) – a complete Metal or OpenGL shader program that fully replaces rendering of a material (fragment shader) or a geometry (vertex shader). Additionally, you can use Shader Modifiers and SCNTechnique. Also, in SceneKit, we can apply beautiful [depth of field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150627/how-to-achieve-realistic-depth-of-field-effect-in-scenekit/55922718#55922718), a cinematic [vignette effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71942611/scenekit-adding-vignette-to-scnview-has-no-effect/71950492#71950492), screen space reflections, and CoreImage filters with animated parameters.

SceneKit's reliable companion is a [Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio) library that carries out import, export, and models' manipulation using a common infrastructure. SceneKit performs a single-threaded rendering (it uses a secondary thread, not the main thread, of course).

iOS app's sample code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scene = SCNScene()
    let options: SceneView.Options = [.autoenablesDefaultLighting]
    let sphere = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.1))

    func createSphere() {
        sphere.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.purple
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
    }
    var body: some View {
        SceneView(scene: scene, options: options)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .onAppear {
                self.createSphere()
            }
    }
}
```

SceneKit reads in several [file formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119378/which-format-file-for-3d-model-scenekit-arkit-better-to-use/55879013#55879013), including `.usdz`, `.dae` and `.scn`. Supports nested asset animation, dynamics, particles, PBR materials, HDR IBL and [spatial audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044242/arkit-spatial-audio-barely-changes-the-volume-over-distance/58050226#58050226). For implicit and explicit transform animation of any node you can use [SCNAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction), [SCNTransaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransaction) and [CAAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation) classes. Though a [collisions' setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337942/arkit-collision-with-real-world-objects) in SceneKit is a little bit complicated. To create a modular and scalable game architecture with SceneKit we need to implement [GameplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit)’s ***entity-component*** pattern.

**Conclusion**: SceneKit gives you a high-quality render technology (but at first you need to setup `physicallyBased` shaders), although for AR projects you can use it only with ARKit. SceneKit is highly customizable and can be used with Swift and Objective-C, and it gives you a set of useful `renderer(...)` instance methods coming from [ARSCNViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate) protocol that allows you update AR models and tracked anchors at 60 fps. Works with UIKit and SwiftUI (despite the fact that there's no `SceneKit+SwiftUI` template in Xcode). There are obvious reasons that Apple might make this framework deprecated during the next 2 years – SceneKit hasn't been updated since 2017, excluding minor changes like [clearCoat](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/3075420-clearcoat) material property, [SSR](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/3075425-wantsscreenspacereflection?changes=l_4) and SwiftUI's [SceneView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72530436/how-to-make-sceneviews-background-clear-in-swiftui/73393260#73393260)). Note that in visionOS, SceneKit content isn't 3D, it's placed as 2D window.

```
         SceneView(scene: SCNScene? = nil,
             pointOfView: SCNNode? = nil,
                 options: SceneView.Options = [],
preferredFramesPerSecond: Int = 60,
        antialiasingMode: SCNAntialiasingMode = .multisampling4X,
                delegate: SCNSceneRendererDelegate? = nil,
               technique: SCNTechnique? = nil)
```

While RealityKit is getting more and more mature, SceneKit boasts [some advantages](https://medium.com/@arkit/the-top-9-most-in-demand-features-for-realitykit-3-0-c1a50f08909d) over RealityKit. At least one thing that Swift developers forget about it, is that Objective-C SceneKit's apps ensure faster compile times.

SceneKit's views are SCNView and SceneView.

```swift
@available(iOS 8.0, tvOS 9.0, *)
open class SCNView : UIView, SCNSceneRenderer, SCNTechniqueSupport 
 
@available(OSX 10.8, *)
open class SCNView : NSView, SCNSceneRenderer, SCNTechniqueSupport

@available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
public struct SceneView : View
```

## Metal | MetalKit

[image]

To be precise, Metal is not a rendering technology but rather the GPU accelerator with the ability of using a rich shading language (MSL). It was released in 2014. It's a low-level framework. Metal is implemented everywhere – in RealityKit, SceneKit, ARKit, CoreML, Vision, AVFoundation, etc. Metal combines functions similar to deprecated [OpenGL ES](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/opengles) and [OpenCL](https://developer.apple.com/opencl/) under the hood of just one API. Of course, Metal can be used as a renderer for advanced 3D graphics. Metal renders not only reflections but also [refractions](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/46936021087389880/) and [subsurface scattering](https://www.pinterest.com/CophiiArt/subsurface-scattering/) phenomena.

**According to Apple documentation**: *"Metal is a C++ based programming language that developers can use to write code that is executed on the GPU for graphics and general-purpose data-parallel computations. Since Metal is based on C++, developers will find it familiar and easy to use. With Metal, both graphics and compute programs can be written with a single, unified language, which allows tighter integration between the two.*"

In addition to Metal, you can use `MetalKit` module (released in 2015) that helps build Metal apps quicker and easier, using far less code. It renders graphics in a standard Metal view, load textures from many sources, and work efficiently with models provided by [Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio) framework.

> Metal begins shining when you render a considerably greater number of polygons or 3D-particles than SceneKit or RealityKit is capable of rendering.

You will be surprised when you know that Metal can be used not only in the Apple ecosystem but also in Windows. Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) where you can download ***Metal Developer Tools for Windows***.

Sample code:

```swift
import MetalKit
    
class RedCube: Primitive { ... }

class CubeScene: Scene {

    override init(device: MTLDevice) {           
        super.init(device: device)
            
        let redCube = RedCube(withDevice: device)
        objects.append(redCube)
        redCube.translate(direction: float3(0,0,-10))
        add(child: redCube)
    }
    override func render(commandEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder, 
                              deltaTime: Float) {
        objects.forEach { 
            $0.rotate(angle: deltaTime, axis: float3(1, 1,-1)) 
        }
        super.render(commandEncoder: commandEncoder, deltaTime: deltaTime)
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**: Developers usually use Metal framework to generate a High-Quality GPU Rendering for games with sophisticated 3D environments, for video processing apps like Final Cut Pro and Nuke, for 3D apps like Maya, or for big data scientific apps that must perform for scientific research. Consider, [raytracing in Metal](http://metalkit.org/2018/07/14/raytracing-with-metal.html) is much more quicker than in RealityKit.

MetalKit's native view is MTKView.

```swift
@available(iOS 9.0, tvOS 9.0, *)
open class MTKView : UIView, NSCoding, CALayerDelegate

@available(OSX 10.11, *)
open class MTKView : NSView, NSCoding, CALayerDelegate
```

## ARKit

[image]

**iOS ARKit** | 2017

Speaking of RealityKit, it's impossible not to mention ARKit. iOS RealityKit, like iOS ARKit, is based on `ARSession` and `ARConfiguration` objects. iOS ARKit is the `umbrella framework` that includes SceneKit, SpriteKit, AVFoundation, Vision, UIKit and CoreMotion dependencies. iOS ARKit is served in both languages ​​- Swift and Objective-C. The framework supports the same type of transform matrices as SceneKit, RealityKit and Metal. iOS ARKit's collaboration with [NearbyInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/nearbyinteraction) framework allows users to acquire the precise position of nearby devices (you can get distance, direction and IDs) with U1+ chips, using the visual capabilities of ARKit. iOS ARKit can capture 4K HDR video. Also iOS ARKit is good at [Geospatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64884844/adding-3d-object-to-argeoanchor/65200766#65200766) tracking. Since RealityKit does not have the `ARGeoAnchor` equivalent, it can only be used in conjunction with ARKit.

**visionOS ARKit** | 2023

ARKit for visionOS has fundamentally different API compared to iOS ARKit. Now both frameworks are [less dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77577395/how-to-know-users-position-in-surrounding-space-in-visionos/77584363#77584363) on each other. The basic principles of ARKit in visionOS remain the same, but the main objects have changed significantly - now they are ARKitSession, DataProvider and [six types of anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502). Needless to say that the new ARKit API is not only more automated but also works in asynchronous context.

You need to provide ARKit data authorization with the help of `NSHandsTrackingUsageDescription` key if your app uses hand tracking. Also use `NSWorldSensingUsageDescription` key if your ARKit app uses plane detection, image tracking, or scene reconstruction features.

The new ARKit API no longer uses the ARWorldMap object explicitly. You just need WorldAnchor object, to activate the `AR Persistence` feature (which registers the ID and Pose for each world anchor).

---

There's no rendering engine inside iOS/visionOS ARKit. In both cases, this module is only responsible for high-quality `Camera/Object Tracking` and `Scene Understanding` features (plane detection, ray-casting, scene reconstruction and light estimation). Also, iOS ARKit is capable of processing data of a [Canonical Facial Meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71544920/how-to-render-a-face-mesh-with-realitykit/74913360#74913360) using ARFaceGeometry class, and manage `Vertices, Normals, Triangular Faces and Classifications` of a reconstructed geometry via ARMeshGeometry class.

Here are five types of views ARKit is able to work with – ARSCNView, ARSKView, ARView, MTKView and RealityView.

```swift
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
open class ARSCNView : SCNView, ARSessionProviding

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
open class ARSKView : SKView, ARSessionProviding

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
@objc open class ARView : ARViewBase

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
open class MTKView : UIView, NSCoding, CALayerDelegate

@available(visionOS 1.0, *)
public struct RealityView<Content> where Content : View
```

If you need more info on ARKit and its capabilities, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811770/are-there-any-limitations-in-vuforia-compared-to-arcore-and-arkit/50816392#50816392).

## USD + Hydra

[image]

Pixar's Universal Scene Description isn't just another file format for 3D graphics' scene descriptions, it's rather an open and extensible ecosystem for describing, composing, simulating, and collaborating within 3D environment. USD files represent the scene as an hierarchy of primitives (or prims), i.e. scene layout, geometry, materials, animations, lights, cameras, transform hierarchies, etc. You can create USD files either thru UI, like in Reality Composer Pro, or [programmatically in Python](https://medium.com/macoclock/augmented-reality-911-usdz-schemas-367ae40c6950). The key feature of USD is the ability of composing layers that present a non-destructive editing.

At the moment there are four members in Universal Scene Description family:

- USDA (ascii)
- USDC and USD (binary)
- USDZ (zip archive)

Another important thing about USD is that it comes with Hydra, which is a medium between current scene graph and renderer. In other words, Hydra is a modern rendering architecture optimized for handling very large scenes. Thanks to Hydra, USD file format supports almost any raytracing renderer - Storm, Metal, Renderman, Vulkan, i.e. Hydra enables a communication between multiple renderers & scene graphs.

[image]

`Hydra` is the imaging framework that ships as part of the USD distribution. It connects `scene delegates`, that consume scene data, and `render delegates`, in such a way that render and scene delegates can be mixed and matched as apps' and consumers' needs dictate. Hydra has incorporated a “graphics interface” abstraction that allows Storm to use Vulkan, Metal, or potentially any rendering API’s. Storm is highly scalable, has multi-pass feature, and uses OpenSubdiv for mesh rendering.

## SpriteKit

[image]

SpriteKit is Apple node-based framework for creating and rendering 2D games and 2D graphics. Was released in 2013. You can use SpriteKit as a standalone API or use it with SceneKit and ARKit. Its main feature is the ability to draw sprites with physics, 2D text and shapes, images and video, and even [to rasterize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71715758/same-color-rendered-differently-in-spriteview-vs-sceneview/71716900#71716900) SceneKit's scenes. In SpriteKit you can write a code in Objective-C or Swift.

A SwiftUI view's object that renders a SpriteKit scene looks like this:

```swift
        SpriteView(scene: SKScene,
              transition: SKTransition? = nil,
                isPaused: Bool = false,
preferredFramesPerSecond: Int = 60,
                 options: SpriteView.Options = [.shouldCullNonVisibleNodes],
            debugOptions: SpriteView.DebugOptions,
            shouldRender: @escaping (TimeInterval) -> Bool = { _ in true } )
```

**Official documentation**: *"SpriteKit is a general-purpose 2D framework that leverages Metal to achieve high-performance rendering, while offering a simple programming interface to make it easy to create games and other graphics-intensive apps. Using a rich set of animations and physics behaviors, you can quickly add life to your visual elements and gracefully transition between screens"*.

SpriteKit works with two view types (UIKit and AppKit). The SwiftUI version is here too.

```swift
@available(iOS 7.0, tvOS 9.0, *)
open class SKView : UIView

@available(OSX 10.9, *)
open class SKView : NSView

@available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
public struct SpriteView : View
```

## RoomPlan

[image]

RoomPlan is a magic wand for architects, interior/game designers, real estate agents and e-commerce representatives. Powered by ARKit and RealityKit, [RoomPlan](https://iosexample.com/demo-using-roomplan-available-on-ios-16/) is a framework that utilizes the RGB camera and LiDAR Scanner on iOS device to create a 3D floor plan of a room, including such characteristics as dimensions and objects' types. Machine learning algorithm is capable of discerning walls, windows, doors, stairs, household appliances, furniture and plumbing.

Framework's on-screen instructions explain how to move the device to capture an interior. When the scan is done, the view displays a small-scale version of the scanned room for user to approve. RoomPlan outputs a result as parametric USDZ model, which makes it easy to modify individual components of the scanned room in 3d software.

RoomPlan uses RealityKit's ARView and has its personal view.

```swift
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, *)
@objc open class ARView : ARViewBase

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
@objc class RoomCaptureView : UIView
```

## AR Quick Look

[image]

AR Quick Look is a zero-config framework that uses RealityKit's rendering engine along with ARKit's heavy processing to anchor a model and display AR experiences. iOS and iPadOS built-in apps, like Safari, Mail or Notes, use AR Quick Look to display `.reality` and `.usdz` models with animation, spatial sound, contact shadows and PBR materials. If your device has a LiDAR scanner it will be used in AR QL app to speed up such important features as plane detection, raycasting and ZDepth perception for people occlusion.

Unlike RealityKit, AR Quick Look automatically plays an animation back if it exists. It boasts an additional `levitation` gesture, fully integrated Apple Pay, capturing photo UI button, share UI button, toggling AR/VR mode button, and dismissing the view.

You can embed AR Quick Look views into your mobile version of website with HTML 5 `rel="ar"` attribute.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="/folder/character.usdz" rel="ar">
                <img src="/folder/char-image.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To use it in your iOS app, you need an instance of [QLPreviewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547956/how-to-use-iphone-lidar-sensor-with-web-app/66832294#66832294) and `QLPreviewItem`.

AR QuickLook's native view controller.

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class QLPreviewController : UIViewController
```

Comment: That’s a great answer! I am using SceneKit mainly to create custom geometry. It’s sad that the LiDAR features are not available for SceneKit. Also wondering what role SceneKit will play in the future ...

Comment: @PeterPohlmann it seems LiDAR stuff is available in scenekit to some degree though. e.g. you can use `arSceneView.session.run(configuration)` where configuration is of type `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` which can `configuration.sceneReconstruction = .meshWithClassification`

Comment: @PeterPohlmann You can forget SceneKit. RealityKit will be its replacement since RealityKit offers a .nonAR mode. SceneKit is single-thread, while RealityKit is multi-threaded. I learned about the .nonAR mode a few days ago.

Comment: SceneKit still outperforms RealityKit... loading more than 1 complex 3d models in RealityKit results in excessive memory leaks and crashes compared to SceneKit. Not usable. Filed a radar for that. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9239141
Also no USDZ export from RealityKit and many other missing features. 
And this year no significant updates for RealityKit. So I'm not even sure if RealityKit will be running on the Glasses,...

Comment: @PeterPohlmann, I have three questions: 1. What models did you use – `usdz` or `reality`? 2. What texture size did these models have? 3. And have you turned off `Depth-Of-Field`, `Occlusion`, `ContactShadows` and `MotionBlur` in RealityKit's `.renderOptions`?

Comment: It's all USDZ files. I made a test app to load multiple copies of Apple´s standard USDZ assets. Just ran it again and it looks much better now. Not many leaks. Should have done it before I commented but it was an issue at the time. Anyhow I'm stuck with SceneKit because of the USDZ export feature but other than that RealityKit would be my choice now obviously. But we should all learn Metal I guess...

Comment: @AndyJazz Awesome synopsis -- so what is your update for 2023+ ??

Comment: @mobibob, I think it'll be something like xrOS (realityOS) 