# How to access the TrueDepth iOS camera using a web application in Safari?

Tags: ios, web-applications, arkit, lidar, truedepth-camera

I want to use the TrueDepth camera on iPhone for a web app I am building because it is more accurate than LiDAR. Trying to find a way to utilize the camera via a web app, but not sure how to go about this.

I have searched Reddit and stackoverflow and found the following post: [How to use iPhone LiDAR sensor with Web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547956/how-to-use-iphone-lidar-sensor-with-web-app/66832294#66832294?newreg=0fd33a6de83b4b7295503b9ebf0fc689) and someone mentioned

"You cannot access the LiDAR scanner's parameters when you enable AR Quick Look via iOS Safari."

Has this changed since 2021? Trying to find a way to access either LiDAR or TrueDepth.