# What is the difference between ARView and ARSCNView?

Tags: scenekit, arkit, realitykit

Simple question. Stunningly, the powers that be at Google haven't presented me with an answer.

I get that ARSCNView uses Scenekit and ARView uses Realitykit. From what I understand RealityKit is newer and higher-level than SceneKit.

But what is the difference in use cases?

What type of app would someone choose ARView for/why and what type of app would someone choose ARSCNView for/why?

Answer (score 8):

ARSCNView is a symbiosis of two technologies – AR and VR. ARSCNView is based on SceneKit's view for iOS with the ability to receive data coming from ARKit's ARCamera and ARSession, and SceneKit's SCNScene. In other words, it's SceneKit's view with ARKit's capabilities. Written in Objective-C and Swift. If you work with ARSCNView, then you have the ability to implement such unique features as animated facial blendshapes, SCNConstraints, and, for debugging purposes, camera movement directly in the view.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
open class ARSCNView: SCNView, ARSessionProviding
```

ARView is a RealityKit class that inherits from ARViewBase (a typealias for the UIView). ARView is capable of working with both AR and VR scenes too. ARView can be used not only with pure RealityKit, but also with RealityKit + ARKit. Written in Swift from scratch. If you work with ARView, then you have the opportunity to implement such unique features as body tracking, raycasting, and automatic tracking targets for AR anchors.

```
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, *)
@objc open class ARView: ARViewBase
```

If you need more details, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505755/high-quality-rendering-realitykit-vs-scenekit-vs-metal/60513052#60513052).