# Can ARKit and ARCore use Beacon as an Anchor?

Tags: arkit, arcore, beacon, aranchor, uwb

We’re trying to anchor a model using an absolute coordinate system.
I’m using a UWB beacon system to know where devices are.
I’m now trying to tell ARKit (or ARCore) where the origin Anchor is.
I’m trying to use a beacon location as the origin.

Is there an anchor type that will accept a real world beacon as its source?

Answer (score 0):

### iBeacon vs UWB

iBeacon is a low-precision Received Signal Strength Indicator (RSSI). With iBeacon, the device position can be estimated with accuracy of 2.5 to 3.5 meters (it's monstrously inaccurate positioning).

A more interesting approach is the "collaboration" of [NearbyInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/nearbyinteraction) and [ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505755/realitykit-vs-scenekit-vs-metal-high-quality-rendering/60513052#60513052) frameworks based on U1 (Ultra-WideBand) chips. This trio will give you an incomparably preciser positioning.