# USD + Hydra as a replacement of SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, usdz

On the [WWDC'22 talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10141/), Apple presents an approach to work natively with USD in Xcode. Also, Apple published [this code to download](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/metal_sample_code_library/creating_a_3d_application_with_hydra_rendering). To be able to use this `USD + Hydra` as a replacement of SceneKit, how would we do to interact with the UI?

If anyone can help with a function like `apply material` in SwiftUI would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

### ...it's not just about SceneKit...

[Pixar's Hydra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505755/realitykit-vs-scenekit-vs-metal-high-quality-rendering/60513052#60513052) is rather an imagery processing library (a part of USD distribution) which connects `scene delegates` (SD) and `render delegates` (RD), allowing you to potentially use any contemporary raytraced renderer. In other words, Hydra enables communication between multiple scene graphs and multiple renderers. You can run Hydra with RealityKit, SceneKit or Metal.

Professional software such as Maya, [Nuke](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/Content/release_notes/nuke_13.0.html) and Houdini are already using Hydra.

Comment: thanks Andy! Yup, I know the demo scheme is USD->Hydra->Storm. 

But how would we write functions to control the scene graph (like we do in SceneKit or RealityKit) on this scheme?

Comment: In the form in which Hydra is currently available for iOS developers, it's impractical to use it. I am 100% sure that very soon Apple will release a convenient Hydra API for Xcode 14. It is quite possible that Hydra will even be implemented in Reality Composer.