# How to set size of WindowGroup in visionOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, swiftui-windowgroup, visionos

I want to set the dimensions of a `WindowGroup` to a specific size when running on visionOS. On iOS and maOS we have the `.defaultSize` modifier for that. When building for visionOS, Xcode offers a slightly different modifier (with an additional parameter called depth):

```
.defaultSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0, depth: 200.0)
```

However this does not seem to have any effect — the size of my window in the simulator remains the same, even after a fresh app install.

**How can I set a `WindowGroup` to a specific size on visionOS?**

Answer (score 5):

### Controlling SwiftUI's Volume dimensions

This method you specified, sets a default size for a volumetric window.

```
func defaultSize(width: CGFloat, 
                height: CGFloat,
                 depth: CGFloat) -> some Scene
```

By default, each parameter (width, height, depth) is specified in points, which translates to 1 millimeter for volumetric scenes at standard system scale. The size of a volumetric scene is immutable after creation. If you want to follow the RealityKit scene-size-paradigm, use the initializer's fourth `in` parameter that allows you to set the size in meters.

For me, the following approach does the trick (read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474607/particle-system-in-realitykit/76474627#76474627) to see the content of a volume in my visionOS app).

```
import SwiftUI

@main struct ParticlesApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()                 // contains RealityKit scene
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)
        .defaultSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0, depth: 2.0, in: .meters)
    }
}
```

### Controlling visionOS Window dimensions

##### visionOS SDK Beta 2 (Xcode 15 Beta 5)

In second beta of visionOS, there are some improvements on 2D window's resizability issue. You can control a size of window that is less or equal to `2m X 1m` (but not greater than this size).

```
@main struct SomeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()                 // contains 2D view
        }
        .defaultSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.5, depth: 0.0, in: .meters)
    }
}
```

[image]

##### visionOS SDK Beta 1

`.windowResizability(..)` modifier and all the other ***resizing*** methods are unavailable in visionOS Beta 1 (Xcode 15 beta 4 and lower).

[image]

You can find the identical question on the [Developers Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732523).

Comment: Thank you Andy!  Do you know if there’s a solution for a non-volumetric window in visionOS, too? (I assume that’s `.windowStyle(.plain)`?)

Comment: Alas, I don't know how to fix this problem yet....

Answer (score 1):

***First*** You can get all Scenes with `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes` method

**And** find the current `UIWindowScene` with traversing all Scenes and `UIWindowScene.session`

Set the UIWindowScene size with `UIWindowScene.requestGeometryUpdate` method

```
// new size
let newSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)
// create GeometryPreferences
let geometryPreferences = UIWindowScene.GeometryPreferences.Vision(resizingRestrictions: .uniform)
//  geometryPreferences set size
geometryPreferences.size = newSize
// set window size with requestGeometryUpdate method
currentWindowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(geometryPreferences)
```