# Which methods does QuickLook employ for depth estimation or SLAM capabilities without a LiDAR scanner?

Tags: ios, computer-vision, augmented-reality, realitykit, quicklook

I recently discovered that there is a "web-AR" feature for mobile iOS devices called QuickLook, where a pre-installed native solution is started for AR viewing of 3D models with SLAM capabilities such as surface detection, feature-tracking (anchoring of the digital object) and occlusion. Now, this worked impressively well, but the device I tested this on was an iPad Pro with a LiDAR scanner. I learned that QuickLook, which is implemented using the RealityKit/ARKit, automatically uses the LiDAR scanner if present which I assume massively enhances depth perception and accuracy.

Can anyone tell me which techniques the underlying frameworks uses to function without additional hardware such as LiDAR? I couldn't find specifics in the documentation about QuickLook. For example, does it use monocamera algorithms to estimate depth? Does it run ML models? I am aware that the utilized frameworks likely have capabilities for all of these, but I want to specifically know how QuickLook handles these hardware/device fallbacks, in which order and whether this is public information.

Comment: Pleaae read AR Quick Look section in this post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505755/realitykit-vs-scenekit-vs-metal-high-quality-rendering/60513052#60513052

Comment: The reason for closing your question is – it's not about programming. However, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in detail how iOS does it, in [Capturing Photos with Depth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/capturing_photos_with_depth#2978408) article.

For compatible [devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599) with back-facing dual camera, `AVFoundation` framework can provide the depth information of every frame in the camera stream.

More useful information can be found in [AVDepthData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata) description.

Here is also an [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata/creating_auxiliary_depth_data_manually) on how depth map can be provided manually using `CoreVideo` APIs.